# how to set the number format for an EditText

Tags: android, numbers, format

I want the number being displayed in my EditText upto 1 decimal place with no leading zeroes e.g. 25.0 not like 025.0

how can i do this?

this is in android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`DecimalFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
String formattedText = format.format(025.0);
editText.setText(formattedText);
```

You will get result in `EditText` as `25.0`

Answer (score 4):

you can set it in xml file. Like

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
```