# EditText custom string formatting

Tags: android, format, android-edittext

I searched every question similar to my problem but didn't get it working. My problem is this:

I want to format a string in `EditText` while typing. The format is this (**it's always a 19 digit number**):

**012345 01 0123456789 0**

As you can see I want to add spaces when they are needed while the user is typing. I know that I have to use the `TextWatcher` but everything I do I don't get what i want.

**Edit**:

Here is the code of my last try:

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           if(s.length() == 7 || s.length() == 10 || s.length() == 21){
                editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                String newValue;
                newValue= s.insert((s.length()-1), " ").toString();
                //Log.d("AFTER",newValue);
                editText.setText(newValue);
                editText.setSelection(newValue.length());
                editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
```

Comment: "but everything I do I don't get what i want." We don't know what you've done. Show us what you tried and we can figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409979/how-to-set-the-number-format-for-an-edittext

Comment: @dymmeh I edited my question, please take a look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go with it.

**main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/editText"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:inputType="number" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int textlength = 0;
     EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
            {

             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
             {

             }

             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
              int count, int after)
             {

             }

             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
              int before, int count)
             {


              String text = editText.getText().toString();
          textlength = editText.getText().length();

          if(text.endsWith(" "))          
              return;

          if(textlength == 7 || textlength == 10 || textlength == 21)
          {
            editText.setText(new StringBuilder(text).insert(text.length()-1, " ").toString());
              editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
          }

             }});

    }
}
```

In this way, I have just managed to add spaces between the digits at particular intervals.

**Note:** I have added extra features to the edittext, so that only numbers can be entered and at the same time the number keyboard only pops up by default. For more on the way for the type of user inputs, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817521/edittext-view-with-keyboard-number-only/13817572#13817572) might help you.

Comment: I already had the `android:inputType="number"`. I tested this and it works great. The "deleting a space" part was the real problem. There is only one little problem there. When a user sets the cursor to a random location that is not the last position the deleting part is not working. I'll try to fix it on my own, but if you can give it a try I would be even more gratefull. Thanks for your time :).

Comment: When I try this I get a stack overflow of afterTextChanged getting called over and over again

Comment: https://wizpert.com/wizdom/best-way-to-set-the-custom-format-for-edittext

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to add a check for reverese while user is deleting character it wont work. Thus u need to check when adding spaces for (start != text.length). In this way, when user is deleting, we won't add spaces.

Comment: @Aksiom check this above