# How to control EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I want to control `EditText` which only accepts int values. User enters numbers then I will add string (easy part). But I want to change it dynamically as user enters numbers. How can I achieve this?

I can do these:
user writes 61, `EditText` output is: 61 min.
user writes 1314, then `EditText` output is: 13 min 14 sec.

Here is the problem:
If user writes 7699, expected `EditText` output will be: 76 min 59 sec.

I think I need a controller thing like `ArrayAdapter`'s `getView()` method. If user writes 1361 then I have to say to phone do not print "13 min 61 sec", just print "13 min 59 sec" in `EditText`. But I dont know how.

Solution I have tried: [How to stop the edit text to add text,when the required format text is entered in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211844/how-to-stop-the-edit-text-to-add-text-when-the-required-format-text-is-entered-i)

Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For allowing only numerical values, you can use `android:inputType="number"` in your EditText XML file

For tracing the value written in the `EditText`, you can listen to the changes of `EditText` using `addTextChangedListener` method, and `TextWatcher` interface

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
    final long DELAY = 2000; // in ms
    field1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.field1);

    field1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
            // Do whatever you want with the updated value
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO: do what you need here
                    // you will probably need to use
                    // runOnUiThread(Runnable action) for some specific
                    // actions


                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            String minsString = "";
                            String secsString = "";
                            switch (s.length()) {
                                case 1:
                                    if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s)) == 0 || Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s)) == 1) {
                                        field1.setText(s + " min");
                                    } else {
                                        field1.setText(s + " mins");
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    field1.setText(s + " mins");
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    minsString = s.toString().substring(0, 2);
                                    secsString = s.toString().substring(2);
                                    if (Integer.parseInt(secsString) > 59) {
                                        secsString = "59";
                                    }
                                    field1.setText(minsString + " mins " + secsString + " secs");
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    minsString = s.toString().substring(0, 2);
                                    secsString = s.toString().substring(2);
                                    if (Integer.parseInt(secsString) > 59) {
                                        secsString = "59";
                                    }
                                    field1.setText(minsString + " mins " + secsString + " secs");
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }

            }, DELAY);

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (timer != null)
                timer.cancel();
        }
    });
```

refering to timer [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063439/android-edittext-finished-typing-event) to prevent the instance update of edit text

Comment: It is going to inner loop itself, never changes anything. Always calling itself again and again before changing text after running `field1.setText` method. I think we cannot write `setText` in `afterTextChanged` method

Comment: I've added timer to the solution to make sure to wait 2secs after user finished typing, and then we'll convert the time to mins & secs.

I've updated the code above.

Answer (score 0):

There is this function from `DateUtils` that you can use, you just need to give it a `Long`.

```java
/**
     * Formats an elapsed time in the form "MM:SS" or "H:MM:SS"
     * for display on the call-in-progress screen.
     * @param elapsedSeconds the elapsed time in seconds.
     */
    public static String formatElapsedTime(long elapsedSeconds) {
        return formatElapsedTime(null, elapsedSeconds);
    }
```

to use it it's really easy, `DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(time)` and it'll print in String your time formatted by `MM:SS`

Comment: Thanks, but you didnt get what I asked. I want to correct the wrong input format dynamically, like: 65 second to 59 second because there cant be more than 59 seconds in a minute.

Comment: what code are you using to display your formatted string ? You might wanna take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java